# max-len to ignore Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, eslint

Is there a way to add an option to ignore regular expressions that are too long? Sometimes those things can get huge.

There are some discuss at https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/3229
Look like there are plan to add ignoreRegex to maxLen.

Is there any walk around for now?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use ignorePattern.

```
"max-len": [
  "error",
  {
    "ignorePattern": "^\\s*(const|let|var)\\s+\\w+\\s+\\=\\s+\\/.*\\/(|i|g|m|ig|im|gm|igm);?$"
  }
]
```

this regex will make eslint igore codes like

```
const a = /asdfadsjl/;
const b = /asdfadsjl/
let c = /asdfadsjl/g
var d = /asdfadsjl/gm;
```

etc..